# attack_wrapper tool for DPA contest isn't working

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cryptography

About tool:
The attack wrapper is a tool used to run and evaluate an attack for DPA contest (http://www.dpacontest.org/home/index.html). It is designed to be run on any Unix-like operating system such as Linux, Mac OS X, etc., and Windows. With this tool, you can develop your attack using almost any programming language (C, C++, Python, Perl...), or using Matlab.

Here you can find a download link and more information about it:
http://www.dpacontest.org/tools/tools.php

When I'm trying to evaluate the data (can be found here http://www.dpacontest.org/v4/42_traces.php) attack wrapper tool just creating empty files and then hangs.

My command:

```
attack_wrapper -d DPA_contestv4_2_k00/DPA_contestv4_2/ -x dpav4_2_index.txt -e v4_2  -t -o results_k0 -f fifo
```

Result:

```
D - Output filename = results_k0 (truncate if exists)
D - FIFO mode
D - Base name for FIFOs = fifo
D - Compatibility mode (v2) = disabled
D - Traces will be read from directory DPA_contestv4_2_k00/DPA_contestv4_2/
D - Using index file dpav4_2_index.txt
D - We will check if traces are available
D - Offsets/Shuffles are not provided to the attack
D - Samples are transfered as floats
I - Reading index file (v4_2)...
D - Total number of traces in the index file = 80000
D - Total number of traces available = 5000
D - Total number of keys in the index file = 16
D - Total number of keys available = 1
D - Key #00 (8249ceb658c71d41d7b734449629ab97): 5000 traces available
D - Key #01 (ef38c2af582a7e6b14255d139e9dbefc): not available
D - Key #02 (79db64df1e68124f6a57372b10e20e63): not available
D - Key #03 (efe61497dacc689fd9828465d3ff812b): not available
D - Key #04 (6a4daad5346e6eb385e1d278d1305089): not available
D - Key #05 (c0f38792d0d49c9f9ab97073f92c54b7): not available
D - Key #06 (389f496d23017d998c90ae1972aeaa0f): not available
D - Key #07 (2f345fbf2cd45942f3d91752cbe43ae7): not available
D - Key #08 (f3522c01495323615bcca67de0075395): not available
D - Key #09 (d4a9c9846bbc91da654eca24f08b9176): not available
D - Key #10 (c32807b275242ebf0f53d4639369980d): not available
D - Key #11 (80ceed788ce14c553ae0329995a5bebe): not available
D - Key #12 (0538cad22e6ca8405e14b4f3c5703c92): not available
D - Key #13 (512bfe6e6c4d2c62afa5f900fcc9cb11): not available
D - Key #14 (5384facaaefd16f38f1359ace6a29037): not available
D - Key #15 (b3e0a2b88e2dcf4bf765f2aad1538588): not available
D - Key # = 0
D - # of traces = 5000
I - Preparing the results file...
I - FIFO Wrapper -> Attack: fifo_from_wrapper
I - FIFO Attack -> Wrapper: fifo_to_wrapper
I - Sending # of iterations (5000)
```

And then nothing happens (endlessly).

I've tried it on Windows 7, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.10 in modes fork and FIFO but the result is the same.

How can I fix it to be able to evaluate the data?

Update:

When I launch my attack after 'Sending...' prompt appears by

```
./attack_by_CPA/py_attack_by_CPA/attack.py fifo_from_wrapper fifo_to_wrapper
```

I got error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack_by_CPA/py_attack_by_CPA/attack.py", line 514, in <module>
    attack.launchAttack()
  File "./attack_by_CPA/py_attack_by_CPA/attack.py", line 377, in launchAttack
    this.samples = np.array([struct.unpack('f', fifoIn.read(4))[0] for _ in range(NUM_SAMPLES)])
  File "./attack_by_CPA/py_attack_by_CPA/attack.py", line 377, in <listcomp>
    this.samples = np.array([struct.unpack('f', fifoIn.read(4))[0] for _ in range(NUM_SAMPLES)])
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

fifo_from_wrapper and fifo_to_wrapper are just empty files:

```
prw------- 1 acan acan        0 апр 14 10:50 fifo_from_wrapper|
prw------- 1 acan acan        0 апр 14 10:41 fifo_to_wrapper|
```

A portion of code opening those files:

```
 def launchAttack(this):
        # Open the FIFOs
        fifoIn = open(this.fifoInName, 'rb')
        fifoOut = open(this.fifoOutName, 'wb')

        # Read the number of traces
        numTraces = struct.unpack('i', fifoIn.read(4))[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you manually launching your attack program after the "Sending..." prompt appears? If you are, could you post the portions of your attack program relevant to reading/writing from the wrapper's stream files?

From the DPA Contest website's "Tools" page:

> If the wrapper uses the FIFO mode (if launches with -f or --fifo, or on Windows), the wrapper creates two special files (two fifos or pipes) to communicate with the attack. **The attack must be launched manually and must  open these two files** (on Unix: xxx_from_wrapper in read-only mode and xxx_to_wrapper in write-only mode; on Windows: \.\pipe\xxx_from_wrapper in read-only mode and \.\pipe\xxx_to_wrapper in write-only mode). Next, to read  data from the wrapper, the attack just have to read from the file xxx_from_wrapper (or \.\pipe\xxx_from_wrapper on Windows) and to send data to the wrapper, the attack just have to write to the file xxx_to_wrapper (or \.\pipe\xxx_to_wrapper on Windows). xxx is replace with the last argument on the command line of the wrapper.

Comment: Hello. thank you for the answer, I added this information to a question.